# Increase HNPROC at macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, jira, macos-mojave, jira-plugin

In Atlassian's Confluence [Jira the "Instance health" plugin tool](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217696/troubleshooting-and-support-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) informs also at [Health Check: Thread Limit](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/health-check-thread-limit-858578685.html) that:

```
"Result
The maximum number of processes for the user account running JIRA is 
currently 2500, which can cause performance issues. We recommend
increasing this to at least 4,096."
```

At

[github/apple/darwin-xnu/bsd/conf/param.c](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/master/bsd/conf/param.c)

that file contains

```
Line 94:    #define HNPROC 2500 /* based on thread_max */
```

so in the macOS

```
$ulimit -u
```

can be max of that value. As it is according to:

```
1) $ sysctl kern.maxproc;
```

2) [How to increase the max user processes hard limit(Mojave)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368011/how-to-increase-the-max-user-processes-hard-limitmojave);

3) [Mac OS X Server v10.6: Understanding process limits](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3854).

The options for this issue:

1) To recompile, reinstall and reintroduce the recompiled version of XNU computer operating system kernel with the increased value for HNPROC parameter into the local version of non-server standalone(Mojave currently) version of macOS?

2) To remove this local version of macOS and to install instead of it Windows OS or Linux OS and to migrate the JIRA instance to Windows or Linux, as listed on the Supported Platforms page as at the suggestion at this [Mac OS X Not Supported by JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/mac-os-x-not-supported-by-jira-301662951.html?utm_medium=logScan&utm_source=STP) web page?

3) To find another possible option or even other possible options?

Answer (score 0):

The question expresses concern about a performance warning, which implies that this Jira instance could be for production use.

If so, you definitely want to move to a supported environment (ie. Linux) regardless and configure the process limits correctly, instead of tweaking parameters (let alone recompiling the kernel) in an unsupported environment such as macOS. If you encounter problems in production in the future, you will want to be able to contact Atlassian Support for help, but you will not be able to do that under macOS.

If this instance is just for testing or development, then the health warning is not particularly important and it can be ignored, unless you intend to have hundreds of users accessing your test machine simultaneously.

Another alternative would be to keep macOS but to run Jira as a container under Docker Desktop for Mac. This will end up running Jira in a Linux VM under the covers.

However, if you do want to continue using macOS directly, here is a good answer describing how to [increase the maximum process count by enabling Performance Mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/373036/69573).